# HTML input type=date Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, html, date, dom

I am wondering if there is an easy way to calculate how long an event lasts with two simple HTML date inputs.

Let's say I have this form:

```
<form>
    <input type="date" id ="select5">  
    <input type="date" id="select5">
</form> `
```

What variables do I use in my javascript function to say the event lasts 10 days, or 20 days according to user input.
I hope I am not too unclear.
Thank you so much for your help,
Andre!

Comment: You are too unclear. Do you mean to want to display the difference between those two fields in days?

Comment: Your controls should not have duplicate IDs, a name attribute would be handy. Getting the difference between two dates in days has been asked here many times before. You might look at the answer to those then post what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you must:

1. Determine if the host supports input type date. If not, you must refactor the input to show the format of date expected as a screen tip
2. Even if input type date is supported, browsers will allow invalid values to be entered (e.g. Chrome allows 31 February) so you **must** validate the value.

Once the the user has provided, the values are validated and date objects have been created:

1. Subtract one date from the other
2. divide by the number of milliseconds in one day
3. round the result to accommodate changes over daylight saving boundaries

Stat with suitable markup, then add script. Hopefully the comments are sufficient, if not, please ask for clarification.

```js
// Set parameter for support of input type date
var supportsTypeDate = (function(){
  var el = document.createElement('input');
  el.setAttribute('type', 'date');
  el.value = '2016-31-01';  // Invalid date value
  return el.type == 'date' && el.value != '2016-31-01';
}());

window.onload = function() {
  // If date is supported, remove screen tip
  if (supportsTypeDate) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dateScreenTip'), function(el) {
   el.style.display = 'none';
 })
  }
}

// Parse and validate date in format dd/mm/yyyy
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

// Parse and validate a date in format yyyy-mm-dd
// Note that a date without a timezone is treated as LOCAL since
// the HTML spec is consistent with ISO 8601
function parseISODate(s){
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[0], --b[1], b[2]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

function calcDays() {

  // Get values
  var startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
  var endDate = document.getElementById('endDate').value;
  
  // Parse to Date objects depending on whether
  // input type Date is supported
  if (supportsTypeDate) {
    startDate = parseISODate(startDate);
    endDate = parseISODate(endDate);
  } else {
    startDate = parseDMY(startDate);
    endDate = parseDMY(endDate);
  }

  // Display error messages if invalid input
  document.getElementById('startDateErr').innerHTML = +startDate? '' : 'Please insert a valid start date';
  document.getElementById('endDateErr').innerHTML = +endDate? '' : 'Please insert a valid end date';
  
  // Get difference in days. If either date is invalid, show empty result
  // Use Math.round to remove any daylight saving changeover effects
  var daysDiff = '';
  if (+startDate && +endDate) {
    daysDiff = Math.round((endDate - startDate)/8.64e7);
  }
  document.getElementById('daysDiff').value = daysDiff;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <br>
  <label for="startDate">Start date<input type="date" class="dateInput" id="startDate"></label>
  <span class="dateScreenTip">dd/mm/yyy</span><span class="errMsg" id="startDateErr"></span>
  <br>
  <label for="endDate">End date<input type="date" class="dateInput" id="endDate"></label>
  <span class="dateScreenTip">dd/mm/yyy</span><span class="errMsg" id="endDateErr"></span>
  <br>
  <label for="daysDiff">Days difference<input readonly id="daysDiff" name="daysDiff">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="calcDays()" value="Calculate days difference">
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

The above is intended to be just a demonstration of what is involved, there is a lot more work to implement it as production quality code.

It could be simplified by asking users to input yyyy-mm-dd format for manually entered dates, however it's probably more user friendly to use the more familiar d/m/y.

Answer (score 0):

Use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to calculate the duration between the two dates entered.

This example produces the difference in days using `asDays()`. You can substitute this method for one of the many methods in the [momentjs docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) for example `asHours()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="date" id="start" onchange="getEventTime()">
    <input type="date" id="end" onchange="getEventTime()">
  </form>
  <script>
     var getEventTime = function(){
       var start = moment(document.getElementById("start").value);
       var end = moment(document.getElementById("end").value);
       console.log(moment.duration(end.diff(start)).asDays());
     }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are assuming that the values returned by the inputs will be parsed correctly, which is not a good idea. Input type date isn't supported by all browsers, so the value returned could be anything. Passing a random string to Moment.js to parse means it will guess at the format, maybe it will get it right, maybe not.

Comment: True, I have not addressed the input problem. The date input is also not reliable enough to use without validation. You could use some moment validation `.isValid();` to check the date is valid.